# How to include extensions in bolt cms?

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

I'm pretty new to this, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Just a simple question: how do you include (or 'call') extensions in .twig files?

I'm trying to include the twitterfeed widget on the sidebar of my bolt site, but I'm not sure how to actually make the extension appear. I've filled in all the twitter handle details, data id etc in the config.yml file, and enabled the extension in the main config.yml file, but how do you get the extension to actually appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enabling the extension, just use `{{ twitterfeed() }}` in your templates. It should work.

Comment: To explain further, each extension exposes (if necessary) its Twig function. Each extension should also have their function(s) documented, so that you know how to use them.